# How to get text which is middle of Tags?

Tags: bash, sed

```
      <li><b> Some Text:</b></li><li><b> Some Text:</b></li>
      <pg>something else</pg> <li><b> Some Text:</b> </li>
      <li><b> Some Text:</b></li>
      <li><b> Some Text:</b> More Text </li> <li><b> Some Text:</b> More Text </li>
```

If this is my input string and

```
      Some Text:
      Some Text:
      Some Text:
      Some Text: More Text 
      Some Text: More Text
```

This is to be my output But I got was only

```
      Some Text:
      Some Text:
      Some Text: More Text
```

This is my shell script function in linux

```
     #!/bin/sh
     sed -n -e 's/.*<li>\(.*\)<\/li>.*/\1/p' $1 > temp
     sed -e 's/<[<\/b]*>//g' temp >out
```

Please give me some ideas  where went wrong.

Comment: Do not parse HTML with `sed` or `awk`; `sed` is designed for line-based editing, and `awk` for field-based tasks. Neither is suitable for general structured text whose elements may span more than one line.

Answer (score 2):

Here is one way with `GNU awk` (the first line is a blank line):

```
$ gawk '
RT=="</b>"||RT=="</li>" && NF {
    gsub(/^ *| *$/,"")
    printf "%s%s",(ORS=!(NR%2)?"":"\n"),$0
}
END { print "\n" }' RS='</?b>|</?li>' file

Some Text:
Some Text:
Some Text:
Some Text:
Some Text:More Text
Some Text:More Text
```

Comment: Really thanks for your help .But is there anyway do this using awk and sed because I am very new to shell script

Comment: @user1574779 What OS are you using? Most likely your `awk` is pointing to `gawk`.

Comment: Linux Mint I try to understand functionality of awk . anyway thanks

Comment: @user1574779 If you meant Linux Mint, then run the exact command with `awk`.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind using a **third-party tool** - the **multi-platform web-scraping utility [xidel](http://videlibri.sourceforge.net/xidel.html)** - it gets as simple as:

```
xidel file.html -e '/li'
```

This extracts the text-only content of all (top-level) `li` elements and prints each on a separate line to produce the desired output.

Answer (score 1):

First things first: *Generally* speaking, use a tool that understands HTML (see my other answer) rather than `awk` or `sed` for HTML parsing - as @chepner succinctly puts it:

> Do not parse HTML with sed or awk; sed is designed for line-based editing, and awk for field-based tasks. Neither is suitable for general structured text whose elements may span more than one line.

Thus, the solutions below work in limited circumstances, but do not generalize well.

---

@jaypal has already provided a **GNU** awk (`gawk`)-specific answer.
Here's one that should work with **all `awk` flavors that accept regexes as input record separators (`RS`)** (such as `gawk`, `mawk`, and `nawk`):

```
awk -v RS='</?li>\n*' '
 /^<b>/ { t=$0; gsub(/<\/?b>/, "", t); gsub(/^ +| +$/, "", t); print t}
' file
```

Older and POSIX-compliant `awk` flavors - such as the BSD-based one in **OSX** - only accept a single, literal char. as `RS`, so the above won't work; on OSX, the following `sed` command achieves the same (works on Linux, too):

```
 sed -E 's/<\/?li>/\'$'\n''/g' file | 
  sed -En '/^<pg>/! { /[^ ]/ { s/<\/?b>//g; s/^ +| +$//gp; }; }'
```

Both solutions trim leading and trailing spaces from the output lines.

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/sh
```

Your first sed line does not what you want it to do:
You will only match ONE occurence per line

```
sed -n -e 's/.*<li>\(.*\)<\/li>.*/\1/p' $1 > temp
this...........................^^
```

which matches....the rest of the line (obviously not what you expected)

One quick workaround is to change every `</li>`  into `</li> plus linefeed` before any other processing.

```
#!/bin/sh

sed -e 's/<\/li>/<\/li>\n/g' "$1" |\
sed -n -e 's/.*<li>\(.*\)<\/li>/\1/p' |\
sed -e 's/<[\/b]*>//g' >out
```

I am no sed expert...somebody else may have an more elegant solution